# Mirror github tags to a different repo

Tags: github, tags

I am trying to mirror GitHub tags in one repo to another while retaining the commit history.  Unfortunately, I can't use git push --mirror.  The repo is too big and the maintainer won't increase the push size.

> git clone repoA
>   cd repoA 
>   git checkout tag

Then I want to push this tag (with commits) to repo B

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When you push any ref, all required objects (and only the required ones) are uploaded to the remote repository.

You do not need to add a repository to your remotes list to push to it, as long as you supply the url on your push command.

`git push http://github.com/repoB tagname`